# Render based on lastmodified field

Tags: datetime

I have two LastModifiedDate fields on two different objects. I want to render text if one date is greater than another date in visualforce. I'm pulling in the data just fine through my controller and I'm thinking my VF code below should work but I've been trying for a few hours now and I feel like I'm missing something very small. Another pair of eyes would be helpful.

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOne.LastModifiedDate} > {!objTwo.LastModifiedDate}">
      Render me if objOne date is greater than objTwo date
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

VF page uses the concept of expression language.So In VF page the expressions inside `{!}` get evaluated, be it a formula or conditional statement or variable/method reference to the controller.

Eg:
`{!all visualforce expression}`

So your rendered should look like this:

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOne.LastModifiedDate > objTwo.LastModifiedDate}">
      Render me if objOne date is greater than objTwo date
</apex:outputpanel>
```

For Example:

**Page:**

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!acclist[0].LastModifiedDate > acclist[1].LastModifiedDate }">
        <apex:inputField value="{!acclist[0].LastModifiedDate}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    public List<Account> acclist{get;set;}

    public AccountController(){
        acclist = [SELECT Id,Phone,Name,Testpick__c,LastModifiedDate FROM Account ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks praveen. Would I have to convert the datetime values to a string? I'm currently getting the error "Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Object"

Comment: @Andrew It worked for me.Am not sure why it isn't working for you. I have updated the answer with a example, check it out.

Comment: praveen : `{!all apex expression here}` in your answer is not technically correct - it is a VF expression, not an apex expression. see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables.htm?search_text=actionSupport

Comment: @cropredy you are right. I didn't use proper term up there. Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer.